# Validar el usuario y password usando LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Buenas Noches quisiera que me puedan ayudar estoy realizando una consulta con **Linq** del lenguaje programacion c# ya que estoy realizando una validacion para un logeo de usuario mi codigo es este :

```
 public class D_Usuario
    {
        private DataModel.DataModelDataContext contexto = new DataModel.DataModelDataContext();
        private DataModel.Usuario objUsuario = new DataModel.Usuario();


        public bool ValidarUsuario(string usuario,string pass)
        {
            int validar=(from p in contexto.Usuario
                             where (p.Usuario1==usuario && (p.Pass==pass))
                         select p);

        }
    }
```

Este es el error de la imagen :

> No se puede convertir implicitamente el tipo **IQueryable<Usuario>** en **int**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lo que estás diciendo en tu consulta actual es que te seleccione los usuarios que coincidan con las condiciones, ese resultado te dará un `System.Linq.IQueryable<DataModel.Usuario>`, entonces el error viene al querer asignarlo a un `int`.

Si deseas validar que un usuario exista, simplemente utiliza el método `Count()`, si existe un registro con esas condiciones te enviará el resultado:

```
int validar = (from p in contexto.Usuario
               where (p.Usuario1 == usuario && (p.Pass == pass))
               select p).Count();
```

Otra forma de resolverlo, es cambiando el tipo `int` por `var`:

```
var validar = (from p in contexto.Usuario
               where (p.Usuario1 == usuario && (p.Pass == pass))
               select p);
```

Aunque no la recomiendo ya que le estás dejando un poco más de trabajo al compilador para que determine el tipo al que le corresponde el resultado.

---

Otra forma de resolverlo es utilizando sintaxis lambda:

```
int validar = contexto.Usuario.Where(t => t.Usuario1 == usuario && t.Pass == pass).Count();
```

Answer (score 1):

Hola esto te puede servir.

Ojo con esta linea, no veo que la uses, si no la usas no la instancies, puedes quitarla.

private DataModel.Usuario objUsuario = new DataModel.Usuario();

```
   public bool ValidarUsuario(string usuario, string pass)
   {
      using(DataModel.DataModelDataContext contexto = new DataModel.DataModelDataContext())
      {
         int validar=(from p in contexto.Usuario
                         where (p.Usuario1==usuario && p.Pass==pass)
                     select p).Count();

             return validar == 0 ? false : true; 
      }
   }
```

El using te ayudará a liberar la memoria del contexto creado. Te aconsejo que solo instancies los objetos cuando los vas a usar.